# How to filter and write to multiple files in Python?

Tags: python, lambda, file-io

I am new to python and stuck on this project for days if anyone could help, thanks.

I am trying to write to multiple output files, with each output file containing the results of a filter from the one original input file. I have put prints statements in the row below filter to show me that the 'item' is being passed to the statement and it is but whenever I look at the output file all that is contained is the headers. So for example, the unique list from column 5 in the csv file is red, blue, green. An output file is created associated with each colour - but the contents are always empty.

Output should be for when item is = blue
Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8

Output should be for when item is = red
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8

Output should be for when item is = green

1,2,3,4,Green,6,7,8

Program below

```
import csv
# opens a the input file and reads in the data
with open('Test_colours_in.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
# prints list of unique values in column 5 of csv of input file
    my_list = set()
    for line in csv_reader:
        my_list.add(line['Name5'])
    print(my_list)

# takes these unique values and creates files associated with each unique value
    for item in my_list:
        with open(item + '_'+'Test.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
            fieldnames = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8']
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            csv_writer.writeheader()

# filters the original file for each item in the list of unique values and writes them to respective file

            filtered = filter(lambda r: r['Name5'] == item, csv_reader)
            for row in filtered:
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

csv input file

Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Blue,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,Green,6,7,8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not you use pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df_col = pd.read_csv('colours.csv')

colours = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green']

for colour in colours:
   df_col[df_col['Name5'] == colour].to_csv(colour + '_out.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return to the top of the file before each filter.

Insert csv_file.seek(0) before the filter line in your code as follows.

```
csv_file.seek(0) # Reposition to front of file
filtered = filter(lambda r: r['Name5'] == item, csv_reader)
```

**Explanation**

*The following code snippets places you at the bottom of file*

```
for line in csv_reader:
    my_list.add(line['Name5'])
```

*Also:*

```
filtered = filter(lambda r: r['Name5'] == item, csv_reader)
for row in filtered:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

> Fix is to reposition to the front of the file before each filter so you're filtering the entire file as desired.